# Why does tortoise svn take so long to update icons after commit? Fix?

Tags: tortoisesvn

This has been bugging me for years - my code is on a local hard drive and I have used tortoise SVN with Windows XP and Windows 7.  After a commit tortoise SVN takes anywhere from 5 minutes to 5 days to update icons.  As you can imagine this is frustrating - I can't immediately tell which files/folders have changed because the state is stuck in pre-commit.  Is there a fix?

Comment: I am not sure why this is the case. It **IS** annoying. I have found that running the "Clean Up" command often resolves this.

Comment: Ok, then I have put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer the "why does this happen" part of your question. But I have found that running the "Clean Up" command often resolves this.